# query optimization for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which takes about 28 seconds on my machine. I would like to optimize it and know if there is any way to make it faster by creating some indexes.

```
select rr1.person_id as person_id, rr1.t1_value, rr2.t0_value 
from (select r1.person_id, avg(r1.avg_normalized_value1) as t1_value 
    from (select ma1.person_id, mn1.store_name, avg(mn1.normalized_value) as avg_normalized_value1 
        from matrix_report1 ma1, matrix_normalized_notes mn1 
        where ma1.final_value = 1 
            and (mn1.normalized_value != 0.2 
            and mn1.normalized_value != 0.0 ) 
            and ma1.user_id = mn1.user_id 
            and ma1.request_id = mn1.request_id 
            and ma1.request_id = 4 group by ma1.person_id, mn1.store_name) r1 
    group by r1.person_id) rr1
    ,(select r2.person_id, avg(r2.avg_normalized_value) as t0_value 
        from (select ma.person_id, mn.store_name, avg(mn.normalized_value) as avg_normalized_value 
            from matrix_report1 ma, matrix_normalized_notes mn 
            where ma.final_value = 0 and (mn.normalized_value != 0.2 and mn.normalized_value != 0.0 ) 
                and ma.user_id = mn.user_id 
                and ma.request_id = mn.request_id 
                and ma.request_id = 4 
            group by ma.person_id, mn.store_name) r2 
        group by r2.person_id) rr2 
where rr1.person_id = rr2.person_id
```

Basically, it aggregates data depending on the `request_id` and `final_value` (`0` or `1`). Is there a way to simplify it for optimization? And it would be nice to know which columns should be indexed. I created an index on `user_id` and `request_id`, but it doesn't help much.

There are about 4907424 rows on `matrix_report1` and 335740 rows on `matrix_normalized_notes` table. These tables will grow as we have more requests.

Comment: Can you add the relevant CREATE TABLE statements, as well as some sample data and your expected results for that data?

Comment: Put some effort into formatting the query so a human can read it.  With 600+ reputation points, you should know how to format code in a question.

Comment: Might want to look at `EXPLAIN` syntax.

Comment: Without understanding the tables involved and what you are trying to achieve, it is going to be impossible to give good advice.  You can generally guess that any query with that number of nested subselects is going to perform poorly. Trying to test different combination of joins, subselects, etc to optimize that would take a lot of background understanding and probably some trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

First, the others are right about knowing better how to format your samples.  Also, trying to explain in plain language what you are trying to do is also a benefit.  With sample data and sample result expectations is even better.

However, that said, I think it can be significantly simplified.  Your queries are almost completely identical with the exception of the one field of "final_value" = 1 or 0 respectively.  Since each query will result in 1 record per "person_id", you can just do the average based on a CASE/WHEN AND remove the rest.

To help optimize the query, your matrix_report1 table should have an index on ( request_id, final_value, user_id ).  Your matrix_normalized_notes table should have an index on ( request_id, user_id, store_name, normalized_value ).

Since your outer query is doing the average based on an per stores averages, you do need to keep it nested.   The following should help.

```
SELECT
      r1.person_id, 
      avg(r1.ANV1) as t1_value,
      avg(r1.ANV0) as t0_value
   from
      ( select 
              ma1.person_id, 
              mn1.store_name, 
              avg( case when ma1.final_value = 1 
                        then mn1.normalized_value end ) as ANV1,
              avg( case when ma1.final_value = 0 
                        then mn1.normalized_value end ) as ANV0
           from 
              matrix_report1 ma1
                 JOIN matrix_normalized_notes mn1 
                    ON ma1.request_id = mn1.request_id
                    AND ma1.user_id = mn1.user_id
                    AND NOT mn1.normalized_value in ( 0.0, 0.2 )
           where 
                  ma1.request_id = 4
              AND ma1.final_Value in ( 0, 1 )
           group by 
              ma1.person_id, 
              mn1.store_name) r1 
   group by 
      r1.person_id
```

Notice the inner query is pulling all transactions for the final value as either a zero OR one.  But then, the AVG is based on a case/when of the respective value for the normalized value.  When the condition is NOT the 1 or 0 respectively, the result is NULL and is thus not considered when the average is computed.

So at this point, it is grouped on a per-person basis already with each store and Avg1 and Avg0 already set.  Now, roll these values up directly per person regardless of the store.  Again, NULL values should not be considered as part of the average computation.  So, if Store "A" doesn't have a value in the Avg1, it should not skew the results.  Similarly if Store "B" doesnt have a value in Avg0 result.